# How to put array element inside grid template area in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I want to dynamically changing some values in grid-area property using JS.

```
var d = ["about", "contact"];
  document.getElementById("container").style.gridTemplateAreas = '"services d[0] d[1] content content content"';
```

Is it possible to place for example d[0] inside these signs ' " to make my website more dynamic? The layout is not changing because JS reads it as a string "d[0]" not as an assigned value, which is "about". I'm going to randomly assigning values from the array, but for this moment I just want to place a specific value.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can simply do that using [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var d = ["about", "contact"];
  document.getElementById("container").style.gridTemplateAreas = `services ${d[0]} ${d[1]} content content content`;
```

1. use `` instead of ""
2. then place your variable inside ${}

Example :

```js
var names = ["Adam","Sara"]

   console.log(`welcome mr.${names[0]} and ms.${names[1]}, Have a nice day :)`)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will remember it for other projects, but it doesn't work in my case. I guess gridTemplateAreas requires extra ' ' signs ? When I tried without placing array value just writing document.getElementById("container").style.gridTemplateAreas = ' "services about content content content content" '; - the layout has changed, but without extra ' ' , the layout hasn't

Answer (score 0):

Thx Mohammed for the tip. To make it work, I've changed `` document.getElementById("container").style.gridTemplateAreas = `services ${d[0]} ${d[1]} content content content`; `` into `` document.getElementById("container").style.cssText = `grid-template-areas: 'services ${d[0]} content content content content';`; ``
Great